# Conditional INNER JOIN returning undesired results

Tags: sql, inner-join

Basically I'm using LEFT JOIN tables to get INVOICE records that belongs to a PERSON.

Quick overview of the tables along with associated records.

```
table INVOICES    table GIGS        table BIDS               table PEOPLE
----------------  ----------------  -----------------------  ---------------- 
id | gig_id       id | bid_id       id | gig_id | person_id  id         
----------------  ----------------  -----------------------  ----------------
1  | 1            1  | 1             1 | 1      | 1          1
                  2  | 2             2 | 1      | 2          2
```

and my join query...

```
SELECT invoices.* FROM invoices 
INNER JOIN gigs ON gigs.id = invoices.gig_id 
INNER JOIN bids ON bids.gig_id = gigs.id 
INNER JOIN people ON people.id = bids.person_id 
WHERE people.id = 2
GROUP BY invoices.id
```

and the returned result...

```
INVOICE RESULT
--------------
id
--------------
1
```

The fact is that `people.id=2` **DOES NOT** have any invoices yet the above join query returned the result as if they did.  How do I ensure that it returns empty when a person does not have any invoices?

Any tips on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am afraid you have simplied the problem out of existance. The query you have right now cannot run at all as the join on bids refernces a field that bids does not have. Nor should the group by be there.

Comment: @HLGEM, thanks for the catch on my error.  I forgot to include the "gig_id" column inside table bids.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and start from the `People` table (the one that has the data which you want to see all of)

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    People.Id,
    invoices.* 
FROM 
    People    
LEFT OUTER JOIN     -- this here *might* be an INNER JOIN
    bids ON people.person_id = bids.person_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN     -- this here *might* be an INNER JOIN
    gigs ON bids.gig_id = gigs.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    invoices  ON gigs.id = invoices.gig_id 
GROUP BY 
    invoices.id
```